# unable to show results of responseJson

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, The problem is I can't seem to understand why this function isn't working correctly. It is for an API I'm doing on National Parks. I thought maybe another set of eyes on it might be able to notice something I don't. I haven't been programming very long and treat everything as a learning experience.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried a number of things and none of them seem to work correctly. I'm new to programming.

```
function showResults(responseJson, params) {
  $('.results-list').empty();
  let html = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < responseJson.data.length; i++) {
    const park = responseJson.data[i];
    const description = park.description;
    const name = park.name;
    const url = park.url;
    const address = park.directionInfo;

    html += `
  <li><h3>${name}</h3>
  <p>Description: ${description}</p>
  <p>Link: <a href="${url}">${URL}</a></p>
  <p>Address: ${address}</p>
  </li>`;
    console.log('ugh');
  }
  $('.results-list').html(html);
  $('.results-page').removeClass('hidden');
}

function parkResults(query, highResult = 10) {
  highResult -= 1;

  const params = {
    api_key: apiKey,
    limit: highResult,
    stateCode: query
  };
  const queryString = formatQueryParams(params);
  const url = searchURL + '?' + queryString;

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(responseJson => showResults(responseJson, query))
    .catch(err => {
      $('.error-message').text(`Error:${err.message}`);
      console.log('?');
    });
}
```

The function isn't working properly according to console.log and but it shows no errors. So, I'm kind of lost on this one. I just would like the function to work properly.

Comment: did you check raw response data and showResults function?
not sure what is response.json.

Comment: It is showing a 200 Code. I will add more code of the showResults function

Comment: change your parameter named params to another name because it is duplicated with a keyword

Comment: Do you see the `ugh` log messages?

Comment: `console.log(responseJson)` , do that we can see, what is in this. and if have data then may be issue with `showResults` function. If `responseJson` is empty, then may be issue with API call..

Comment: In api calls in JS, this is normal, that before code runs without waiting for response. so if this is the case, then you have to make your API call async

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine.  I've simplified the code to something others can use and replicate.  The `fetch(...)` looks fine, so I'd recommend you look at your URL and output formatting for weirnesses.

Note, I've removed any scope declarations as well as the multiline string formatting (backticks).  Feel free to add them back in as needed.

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="results-list">Please wait...</p>
<script>
function showResults(json) {
    var element = document.getElementById('results-list');
    element.innerHTML = '';
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        var park = json.data[i];
        html += '<li><h3>' + park.name + '</h3>' +
            '<p>Description: ' + park.description + '</p>' +
            '<p>Link: <a href="' + park.url + '">' + park.url + '</a></p>' +
            '<p>Address: ' + park.directionInfo + '</p>' +
            '</li>';
    }
    element.innerHTML = html;
}

function fetchPark() {
    var url = 'https://developer.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?parkCode=acad&api_key=SECRET_YOU_CAN_GET_ONE_AT https://www.nps.gov/subjects/developer/get-started.htm';

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => showResults(json))
    .catch(err => { console.error(err); });
}

fetchPark();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:

> #### Acadia
>
> Description: Acadia National Park protects the natural beauty of the highest 
>   rocky headlands along the Atlantic coastline of the United States, an abundance 
>   of habitats with high biodiversity, clean air and water, and a rich cultural 
>   heritage. Each year, more than 3.3 million people explore seven peaks above 
>   1,000 feet, 158 miles of hiking trails, and 45 miles of carriage roads with 16 
>   stone bridges.
>
> Link: https://www.nps.gov/acad/index.htm
>
> Address: undefined

Also, beware of strange stuff like proxies or antivirus getting in the way.  Anything that can intercept HTTP traffic should be ruled out when not getting an expected response.